# What would be the MongoDB C# driver equivalent of the following query using the array update operator $[<identifier>]

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

From [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up.*S*[%3Cidentifier%3E]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

Given the following collection

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 80, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 90, "std" : 4 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 6 }
   ]
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "grades" : [
      { "grade" : 90, "mean" : 75, "std" : 6 },
      { "grade" : 87, "mean" : 90, "std" : 3 },
      { "grade" : 85, "mean" : 85, "std" : 4 }
   ]
}
```

and query

```
db.students2.update(
   { },
   { $set: { "grades.$[elem].mean" : 100 } },
   {
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "elem.grade": { $gte: 85 } } ]
   }
)
```

How would I do this same query using the C# driver? At the moment I'm just running the query against the database using `db.RunCommand` as I couldn't see a way to convert this to C# with the current driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below c# using both `BsonDocument` and json string option. There is no linq option.

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("grades.$[elem].mean", 100);
var arrayFilter = new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("elem.grade", new BsonDocument("$gte", 85)));
var arrayFilter = new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>("{ \"elem.grade\": { $gte: 85 } }");
var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> { arrayFilter };
var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
updateOptions.ArrayFilters = arrayFilters;
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: Do you mean for the last kine to be `var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, arrayFilter);`?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more strongly typed version but this is still better than using `RunCommand`. If no better answers will mark correct later. Also, I take it you meant to remove one of the `var arrayFilter=`?

Comment: Np. There is no strongly typed version available so far. I'll update if C# driver supports it in the future. Yes you should use any one. Just showing two different options.

Comment: Didn't know ArrayFilters had been added.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry again. Updated.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With [driver 2.17.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.17.1) which allows to use the `Linq3 provider` and the `AllMatchingElements` method:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;


var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
settings.LinqProvider = LinqProvider.V3; // important!! works with <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.17.1" />
var collection = new MongoClient(settings).GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<GradesDocument>("GradesCollection");

collection.InsertMany(new List<GradesDocument>
{
    new (1, new List<GradeRecord>
    {
        new (80,75,6),
        new (85,90,4),
        new (85,85,6),
    }),

    new (2, new List<GradeRecord>
    {
        new (90,75,6),
        new (87,90,3),
        new (85,85,4),
    }),
});


var identifier = "whatever";
var filter = Builders<GradesDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var update = Builders<GradesDocument>.Update.Set(a => a.Grades.AllMatchingElements(identifier).Mean, 100);
var arrayFilter = new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument($"{identifier}.{nameof(GradeRecord.Grade)}", new BsonDocument("$gte", 85)));
var arrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition> { arrayFilter };
var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions
{
    ArrayFilters = arrayFilters
};
var result = collection.UpdateMany(filter, update, updateOptions);


public record GradesDocument(int Id, List<GradeRecord> Grades);
public record GradeRecord(int Grade, int Mean, int Std);
```