# MongoDB: Query Builder to Update Field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, updates

I'm trying update a field in my mongodb collection with c# driver.

:: The Person Object

```
{
   Name: 'Person1'
   Prefers: [
       { Name: 'Prefer1', Location: 'Lisbon', 
        Sports: [ { Name: 'Sports1', Indoor: true, OutDoor: false } ]
   ]
}
```

My 'Sports' objects is a List of interface: ISports

How I update the field Person.Prefers.Sports.Name?

The next code don't work for me:

```
    var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.And(
      Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq(i => i.Id, X),
      Builders<Person>.Filter.ElemMatch(i => i.Prefers, i => i.Id == Y)
      Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("Person.Prefers.Sports.Id", Z)
 );

var update = Builders<Person>.Update.Set("Prefers.Sports.$.Name", "Sports2");

UpdateOne(filter , update);
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your mongo server version and c# mongo driver version ?

Comment: Mongo Server: 3.6.2 and Mongo Driver Version: 2.5.0

Comment: See if this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876880/what-would-be-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-equivalent-of-the-following-query-using/48877358#48877358).