# Update list of list of list array mongo update

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, document

> ```
> {
>   "_id": "111de970-4f3f-4ae6-9d3b-396e60ff50aa",
>   "ClaimNumber": 111,
>   "Details": [
>     {
>       "Amount": "100",
>       "Types": [
>         {
>           "InvoiceType": "OO",
>           "Status": "N"
>         },
>         {
>           "InvoiceType": "PP",
>           "Status": "N"
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "Amount": "100",
>       "Types": [
>         {
>           "InvoiceType": "OO",
>           "Status": "N"
>         },
>         {
>           "InvoiceType": "SS",
>           "Status": "N"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

```
public class Type
{
    public string InvoiceType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public List<Type> Types { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public int ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

I Would like to update the values of Types array  "Status" = "**P**" in the **Details** array when the "_id" column  and "Types.InvoiceType" = "**OO**" value matches.

Please provide me an example on how to achieve in c# using mongo driver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What would be the MongoDB C# driver equivalent of the following query using the array update operator $\[<identifier>\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876880/what-would-be-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver-equivalent-of-the-following-query-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
var filter = Builders<RootObject>.Filter.Eq(o => o._id, "111de970-4f3f-4ae6-9d3b-396e60ff50aa");
var update = Builders<RootObject>.Update.Set($"{nameof(RootObject.Details)}.$[].{nameof(Detail.Types)}.$[elem].{nameof(Type.Status)}", "P");
var arrayFilter = new JsonArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>($"{{ 'elem.{nameof(Type.InvoiceType)}': 'OO' }}");
var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions { ArrayFilters = new[] { arrayFilter } };
var result = new MongoClient()
    .GetDatabase("database")
    .GetCollection<RootObject>("collection")
    .UpdateOne(filter, update, updateOptions);
```

Comment: Will this code update all details array child values in a single update.? And is there any option to create a  linq expression to avoid hardcoded values in the filter definition?...

Comment: Yes, all matching array values will be updated in a single query. And, yes, it should be possible to write some parts in a nicer fashion. I can try to optimize that if you post the relevant C# types.

Comment: Thank much for the quick response and works like a charm.